# Does Tor hide data from my company router?

Tags: tor

If I use Tor at work, can my system administrators see my activity or is it encrypted? I realize that outgoing traffic to the ISP, etc, will be encrypted but what about to the internal router?

Comment: You may be interested in reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)#Weaknesses

Comment: @Shamoon - Your system administrators have other ways to track your web activity.  Your use of a proxy or TOR won't stop those methods.

Comment: I'm sure of it. I'm not referring to **complete** anonymity. Just wondering more about the details of the Tor implementation

Comment: Dont do anything on a company computer that you wouldnt do if your boss was standing behind you looking over your shoulder.  As @Ramhound said, there are other ways to monitor your activity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They can't get the data.  Tor encrypts data before it is sent through the network.  Keep in mind the random exit node on the other side decrypts it before sending it to its intended destination.  So the exit node can of course sniff that outgoing traffic and record it.  Your company's router cannot.

But ... the list of Tor node IPs is public information, so they may know that you are using Tor based on the destination IP of your outgoing traffic.  They also can measure/record the amount of traffic you are sending and record the time of day that you are sending it.  This could be used to determine reasonable suspicion that you are transferring specific files or performing specific types of activity.